# Which of the following is faster?

Tags: javascript

Which of the following is faster? And, just by the way, which would you personally prefer? (The position variable stores the CSS position of a DIV element.)

**1)**

```
if (/(relative|absolute|fixed)/).test(position) { ... }
```

**2)**

```
if (!(/^s/).test(position)) { ... }
```

**3)**

```
if (position == 'relative' || position == 'absolute' || position == 'fixed') { ... }
```

**4)**

```
if (position === 'relative' || position === 'absolute' || position === 'fixed') { ... }
```

**5)**

```
if (position != 'static') { ... }
```

**6)**

```
if (position !== 'static') { ... }
```

Comment: Why don't you measure the time each one takes?  If you can't measure the difference, does it matter?

Comment: 3) and 4) look broken to me. Did you mix up `and` and `or`?

Answer (score 3):

Try it out for your self on http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 0):

number 5 or 6

Regex have a time complexity of O(mn). 3) and 4) require 3 checks each.

Anyway, you should preform each a 1000 time or so a loop and time them, so you have some experimental evidence on your platform.

Comment: And you base that statement (#5 is fastest) on what? *Why* is it the fastest?

Comment: Regex have a time complexity of O(mn). 3 and 4 require 3 checks each, and 6 has to check type as well.

Comment: Cool, now edit your answer and add this to it... Just saying #5 is fastest isn't a *high quality* answer. Also as the OP mixed up his boolean logic your answer may have to change anyway.

Comment: You don't think number 5 checks type?

Comment: @patrick, probably you're right, the average of a thousand test runs on 10000 operations on my machine show that there is no real difference between 5 and 6.

Comment: @Griffin: Yeah, they both start by testing the type of both operands. If the types are the same, they're effectively identical. If the types are different, the `===` returns `false` immediately, whereas the `==` enters an algorithm that performs type coercion. If they can be coerced to a matching type with an equal value, it returns `true`, otherwise `false`.